# How can I hook into route change on frontend and redirect before it hits the backend, on Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I have a sort of curious feature I would like to implement, which I think requires hooking into the router on the frontend in Next.js, and adjusting the URL query parameters based on `localStorage` to include global configuration settings. This way when they visit "bare" links, it *actually* takes them to the link based on their saved configuration.

For example, say I have a global configuration for "font" in the app, only on the pages with fully Hebrew content. It is added as a query parameter like `?font=Google-Noto-Hebrew` when they configure their settings for the Hebrew section of the website. Then when they are clicking around in the site, it keeps the `font=Google-Noto-Hebrew` query parameter in the URL, even though all the `<a href="...">` link tags use URLs without the `font` query parameter! It somehow would intercept when the link would be clicked, and checks `localStorage` for any query parameters to adjust in the URL, and adds/removes any of them that are global settings. That way, visiting this:

```
/my/hebrew/text
```

"Redirects" to:

```
/my/hebrew/text?font=Google-Noto-Hebrew
```

This way, when they copy the URL and share it, the people who click that link will be taken to the page with the chosen font, so fonts are linkable!

But if this current customer, who has chosen Google Noto Hebrew as their base font, visits this link which someone else shared:

```
/my/hebrew/text
```

Then they would be taken to this link, as they would expect:

```
/my/hebrew/text?font=Google-Noto-Hebrew
```

If however some other customer shared this link to our original customer:

```
/my/hebrew/text?font=Other-Hebrew-Font
```

Then the original customer would see that font, not their chosen font. They would just go to that same URL:

```
/my/hebrew/text?font=Other-Hebrew-Font
```

This wouldn't change their global settings, only visiting the settings panel would do that. But as long as they were clicking around the site coming from this link, it would keep that parameter around, so all pages were viewed with this new font.

To turn it back to their original font, they would have to go back to the settings and select it again.

That is at least what I am currently thinking.

The reasoning behind this is so that the customer can view dozens/hundreds of pages of a book (each with their own URL), using a consistent font *which can at the same time be changed*. And such that the `<a>` link tags are consistent for SEO purposes with Server-Side-Rendering, they never include the `?font=X` parameter, they are without these sort of parameters. And when the customer comes back to the site from a link without the font parameter, it gives them the pages how they "normally" see them, which is using their default selected font. I think that would be pretty nice.

How can I do this in Next.js? Can I hook into the `router.on('change')` sort of events, and adjust query parameters *before* the URL changes and possibly hits the backend?

I am currently thinking of just creating my own `<Link>` component, which intercepts the `<a>` click, and adjusts the query parameters with the global settings. But that will quickly get kind of hard I think, I'm not sure. Because I have complex dynamic URL paths, about 100 of them so far, like `/[a]/[b]/[c]/[d]/[e]`, and I would have to somehow figure out how to convert the actual path like `/foo/bar/baz` into `/[a]/[b]/[c]` sorts of things, which seems a bit complex at this point.

I can't think of any other potential solutions really at this point, I will have to let it simmer, but wanted to see if you knew how to intercept Next.js router calls on the frontend when a link is clicked, *before it hits the backend and makes the API call to load data*.